# home and back buttons for file browser android

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm implementing a simple file browser and I've got navigation working (thanks to online sources) now I want to make a home and back button to navigate directly to the set root and to the parent directory respectively. I made an actionbar and added two buttons but I don't know how to get them to function properly. The last function is for setting the button functions. Sorry in advance if I'm not posting the code properly
The following is the code I have (I'm extending ListActivity):

```
 private List<String> item = null;
 private List<String> path = null;
 private String root;
 private TextView myPath;
 private File f;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    getDir(root);
}

private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
 myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
 item = new ArrayList<String>();
 path = new ArrayList<String>();
 f = new File(dirPath);
 File[] files = f.listFiles();

 if(!dirPath.equals(root))
 {
  //item.add(root);
  //path.add(root);
  item.add("../");
  path.add(f.getParent()); 
 }

 for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
  File file = files[i];

  if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
   path.add(file.getPath());
      if(file.isDirectory()){
       item.add(file.getName() + "/");
      }else{
       item.add(file.getName());
      }
  } 
 }

 ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rows, item);
 setListAdapter(fileList); 
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File file = new File(path.get(position));

    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        if(file.canRead()){
            getDir(path.get(position));
        }else{
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show(); 
        } 
    }else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.home:
        path.add(root);
        return true;

    case R.id.back:
        path.add(f.getParent());
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**end of code
Thank you

Comment: edited my post to add more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using listview, try to do mListView.invalidateViews().
If you are using listActivity, just call mList.invalidateViews().

Comment: thank you for replying. I don't really understand your answer; where exactly should I call this method and what does it do? This is my first attempt at an app so I don't know too much.

Comment: In your funtion onOptionsItemSelected() after call path.add(XX) before return statement.

Comment: what should be in place of mList with respect to my code? (you said call mList.invalidateViews())

Comment: I am sorry I think this is not a place where you get free code. This is a place you asking for directions and you have to walk your own ways.

Comment: ...I'm not trying to get free code, I just don't know what to do with the function even though I looked it up on android's dev site. I've posted before on this site so I know what it is; your answer just isn't helpful enough for a complete newbie to android. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Fixed it. Didn't use your method though.